# Account Link label generated by helper returns escaped html

Tags: magento2, helper, svg

In a link block I am calling a helper function to return a label with a piece of svg:

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link" after="top.links.right.search">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="helper" helper="Vendor\Module\Helper\Data::svg">
            <param name="id">login</param>
            <param name="label">My Account</param>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

The helper function looks like this:

```
public function svg($id, $label = null)
{
    $ssl = $this->_request->isSecure();
    $file = $this->_assetRepo->getUrlWithParams('svg/sprite.svg', array('_secure' => $ssl));
    $class = 'svg-' . $id;
    return '<svg class="' . $class . '"><use xlink:href="' . $file . '#svg-' . $id . '"/></svg>' . $label;    
}
```

The SVG is created properly. Unfortunately it is returned as escaped html and thus printed in clean text.

How can I prevent the generated svg from being escaped?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it. 
Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link renders the links as follows:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    return '<li><a ' . $this->getLinkAttributes() . ' >' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getLabel()) . '</a></li>';
}
```

If no template is present it returns default link html with an escaped label. 
So by explicitly setting a template in the layout I can tell magento what template to use for this particular link:

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link" after="top.links.right.search" template="Vendor_Module::link.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="helper" helper="Vendor\Module\Helper\Data::svg">
            <param name="id">login</param>
            <param name="label">My Account</param>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

That template looks like this:

```
<?php if (!$block->getIsDisabled()): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getHref()) ?>"
            <?php if ($title = $block->getTitle()):?> title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__($title)) ?>"<?php endif;?>>
            <?= $block->getLabel() ?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```